# GDRIVE :syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: ubuntu, gdrive

I've been using Gdrive for a while and it helped me save a lot of time but now when I tried installing it elsewhere I get

```
/usr/local/bin/gdrive: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/bin/gdrive: line 2: <! DOCTYPE HTML>
```

I'm following this [tutotrial](https://olivermarshall.net/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-from-the-command-line/) so I if you fixed it please help me fix it too and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose the correct version for your machine type. You can find it in https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/releases.